# java + sqlite: how to open database as read-only?

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc, readonly

I have a large database that I want to open in read-only mode... I'm using [SQLiteJDBC](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/) and am not sure what to use to get it to work as read-only.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 13):

[Test](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/blob/master/src/test/java/org/sqlite/ConnectionTest.java#L64) demonstrate how to set connection to be read-only:

```
SQLiteConfig config = new SQLiteConfig();

config.setReadOnly(true); 

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:sample.db",
config.toProperties());
```

Comment: ??? Where do I get SQLiteConfig from? It doesn't seem to be visible from SQLiteJDBC  v056.

Comment: Thanks but no, it's not part of the standard release of SQLiteJDBC.

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
Properties config = new Properties();
config.setProperty("open_mode", "1");  //1 == readonly
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:sample.db", config);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just want to add that when using [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP), you need *two* datasource properties:

```
readOnly=true
dataSource.open_mode=1
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a slightly different scenario, but the same issue. If you have a spring boot service using Hikari you need to provide 2 configuration settings in your application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlite:myDatabase.db?open_mode=1
spring.datasource.hikari.read-only=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across your post and this is what helped me:
I made a connection similar to the one listed here http://www.shoaibinamdar.in/blog/?p=313 but insread of

```
    ds.setUrl("jdbc:sqlite::resource:"+
    getClass().getResource("sample.db").toString());
```

I put

```
    ds.setUrl("jdbc:sqlite:resource/sample.db");
```

the sample.db went in /myprojectname/resource/sample.db, with resource being in the same dir (myprojectname) as /myprojectname/src/

Hope this helps someone